# Can potly graph objects be used with Azure Data Explorer?

Tags: python, azure, plotly, scatter-plot, kql

I managed to create a scatter plot by evaluating a **plotly** snippet into a **Kusto** query into **Azure Data Explorer** (ADX):

````
let varName = ```if 1:
        import plotly.express as px
        import pandas as pd
        fig = px.scatter(df, x='easting', y='northing')
        fig.update_layout(title=dict(text="Test, plotly 2"))
        plotly_obj = fig.to_json()
        result = pd.DataFrame(data = [plotly_obj], columns = ["plotly"])
```;

data_delivery_report
| project easting, northing
| evaluate python(typeof(plotly:string),
varName)
````

I would prefer to use **graph_objects** instead of **plotly express**.

Alas, the KQL query fails to return any data when I replace the above script with:

````
let varName = ```if 1:
        import plotly.graph_objects as go
        import pandas as pd
        fig = go.Scatter(x=df['easting'], y=df['northing'])
        fig.update_layout(title=dict(text="Test, plotly 2"))
        plotly_obj = fig.to_json()
        result = pd.DataFrame(data = [plotly_obj], columns = ["plotly"])
```;
````

Is ADX supporting plotly graph_objects? I checked [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer-blog/plotly-visualizations-in-azure-data-explorer/ba-p/3717768) but could not find any information about that topic.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, @SPT. Solution accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

> Can potly graph objects be used with Azure Data Explorer?

Yes, Below is the **`KQL query`** which worked for me:

````
table1
|project Id,Name,Age,marks
| evaluate python(typeof(plotly:string),
```if 1:
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    fig =  go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=df['Id'], y=df['Name'])])
    plotly_obj = fig.to_json()
    result = pd.DataFrame(data = [plotly_obj], columns = ["plotly"])
```)
````

[image]

**`Output of Json is:`**

[image]

Here I have used `go.Figure()` to get the expected output, try to integrate your query with mine to get required output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @RithwikBojja! I had to use `mode='markers'` to reproduce the initial plot created with plotly express but apart from this detail, your solution worked straight out of the box!

Comment: @Sheldon, Glad it worked.

Comment: @RithwikBojja: per your advice, the related question (Graph Objects in an ADX dashboard) was asked as a new question.  Thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77238665/how-to-plot-a-gauge-chart-using-plotly-graph-objects-library-in-azure-data-e

Comment: @GHariz, Sure will check on it