# how to plot a Gauge chart using - Plotly Graph Objects library - in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python, azure-data-explorer

How can the Plotly Graph Objects Python library be used to plot a **Gauge chart** in an **Azure Data Explorer dashboard**.

Kusto (with Python plug-in) may be used in an Azure Data Explorer Dashboard to graph a Python Plotly chart (e.g. a bar chart or a scatter chart) using the Plotly Express library.

However, Plotly Express **CANNOT** draw a Gauge Chart.  Hence, the [Graph Objects](https://plotly.com/python/graph-objects/) library needs to be used.

This ADX code does work (with value hard set to 250):

````
['table']
| where abs(Prsr1IoTVal) >= 1 
| top 1 by IoTEventDateTime
| project  Pressure1Value=round(Prsr1IoTVal)
| evaluate python(typeof(plotly:string),
```if 1:
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
        mode = "gauge+number",
        value = 250,
        domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
        title = {'text': "Speed"}))
    plotly_obj = fig.to_json()
    result = pd.DataFrame(data = [plotly_obj], columns = ["plotly"])
```)
````

However, we tried setting the value to be the value passed in from the Kusto table - no rows are returned (even though we know the Kusto query does return a value):

````
['glualwndpwriotevents-target-tbl']
| where abs(Prsr1IoTVal) >= 1 
| top 1 by IoTEventDateTime
| project  Pressure1Value=round(Prsr1IoTVal)*100
| evaluate python(typeof(plotly:string),
```if 1:
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    fig = go.Figure(
                    data=[go.Indicator(
                                mode = "gauge+number",
                                value = df['Pressure1Value']
                                domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
                                title = {'text': "Speed"}
                                )
                        ]
                    )
    plotly_obj = fig.to_json()
    result = pd.DataFrame(data = [plotly_obj], columns = ["plotly"])
```)
````

> > Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: `value` sets the (unique) number to be displayed, you need to do something like `value=df['Pressure1Value'].values[i]` where `i` is the index of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

I observed from your query or python code is that, you are passing data frame object, the value expects it to be  scalar value.

Below is the **`KQL query`** (modified your query a bit) which worked for me:

````
rithtable
|project Name,Age
| evaluate python(typeof(plotly:string),
```if 1:
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    value = df['Age'].iloc[0]
    fig = go.Figure(
                    data=[go.Indicator(
                                mode = "gauge+number",
                                value = value,
                                domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
                                title = {'text': "Speed"}
                                )
                        ]
                    )
    plotly_obj = fig.to_json()
    result = pd.DataFrame(data = [plotly_obj], columns = ["plotly"])
```)
````

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`Output of Json is :`**

[image]